# MongoDB not in any array (nested arrays)

Tags: arrays, mongodb

We have scheme like this

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5e2ebceb2fb28c43520ef313"), 
"attempts" : [
    {
        "ideas" : [
            {
                "ideaId" : ObjectId("5d314e8ade83a139bf31352a"), 
                "ratings" : [
                    {
                        "userId" : "20-432-3", 
                        "points" : 3.0, 
                        "isBest" : true
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "ideaId" : ObjectId("5d314e8ade83a139bf31352c"),
                "ratings" : [
                    {
                        "userId" : "20-432-2", 
                        "points" : 3.0, 
                        "isBest" : true
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "ideaId" : ObjectId("5d314e8ade83a139bf31352e")
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to to update document only if it does not have given userId in `attempts.ideas.ratings`. For example when user with userId with "20-432-3" want to update document, it will fail (because there is already rating from him in first idea), on the other hand user with userId "20-432-1" can update document.

it's like 3 nested scheme, my question is: is it possible in one query???

thank you in advance

EDIT.

Found solution. Obviously it was the easiest way...

```
_id: ObjectId("5e2ebceb2fb28c43520ef313"),
 "attempts.ideas.ratings.uuIdentity": { $ne: "20-432-1" }
```

Comment: Are you looking for a query to fetch if for a given `userId`, a rating exists?

Comment: No no, i want to use it as update command, i trying to create query which will find only such document, like iam using _id of document, but find it only if it doesn't have rating from that particular person. Side story: Every user can rate only one idea.